# Angular Dynamic templates with different CSS, JS and JS files and jQuery versions

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, typescript

I am building an Angular application whereby users have the ability to select HTML(CSS, jQuery, JS) templates for their site. All templates are totally different from one another. For example, template one can have Bootstrap version 3 and jQuery verison 3. Template 2 can have Bootstrap version 5 and jQuery 2.

So far, I have this working by using lazy loaded routes and dynamically adding scripts to the files.
The issue with this is sometimes, the scripts do not load.
Is there something I'm doing wrong or is there a better way to handle such a problem?

Adding styles dynamically using a service

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject, Injectable, Renderer2, RendererFactory2 } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CssColinaService {
  private renderer2!: Renderer2

  constructor(rendererFactory: RendererFactory2,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: Document,
  ) { this.renderer2 = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null)}

  loadScripts() {

    const dynamicStyles = [
      "../../../../assets/colina/css/bootstrap.css",
      "../../../../assets/colina/css/animate.css",
      "../../../../assets/colina/css/font-awesome.css",
      "../../../../assets/colina/css/linear-icons.css",
      "../../../../assets/colina/css/hotel-icons.css",
      "../../../../assets/colina/css/magnific-popup.css",
      "../../../../assets/colina/css/owl.carousel.css",
      "../../../../assets/colina/css/datepicker.css",
      "../../../../assets/colina/css/theme.css",
      "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,500&amp;subset=latin-ext",
      "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,700&amp;subset=latin-ext",
    ];

    for (let i = 0; i < dynamicStyles.length; i++) {
      const node = this.renderer2.createElement('link');
      node.href = dynamicStyles[i];
      node.rel = 'stylesheet';
      this.renderer2.appendChild(this._document.body, node);
    }
  }
}
```

Adding scripts and jQuery dynamically using a service

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject, Injectable, Renderer2, RendererFactory2 } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class JsColinaService {
  private renderer2!: Renderer2

  constructor(rendererFactory: RendererFactory2,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: Document,
  ) { this.renderer2 = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null)}

  loadScripts() {

    const dynamicScripts = [
      "../../../../assets/colina/js/jquery.min.js",
      "../../../../assets/colina/js/jquery-ui.js",
      "../../../../assets/colina/js/jquery.bootstrap.js",
      "../../../../assets/colina/js/jquery.magnific-popup.js",
      "../../../../assets/colina/js/jquery.owl.carousel.js",
      "../../../../assets/colina/js/main.js"
    ];

    for (let i = 0; i < dynamicScripts.length; i++) {
      const node = this.renderer2.createElement('script');
      node.src = dynamicScripts[i];
      node.type = 'text/javascript';
      this.renderer2.appendChild(this._document.body, node);
    }
  }
}
```

Calling the services to a component

```
constructor(
    private c: CssColinaService,
    private j: JsColinaService,
  ) { 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.c.loadScripts()
    this.j.loadScripts()
  }
```

Comment: Regarding `Is there something I'm doing wrong`, then it's very hard to tell you without seeing the code.

Comment: Sharing the codes